# Java - How to traverse Binary Search Tree Recursively Without Parameters

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having some trouble with a coding project of mine. The program is a Binary Search Tree that holds WordCount objects. These hold just two fields, a String for a word and an integer that holds the number of times that the word appears in a text file.

The method I'm having trouble with requires traversing the tree in order to find the most common word. I've implemented a method that would do the trick, but I just found out that the method is supposed to be recursive and not use a parameter.

The method I've already written is here:

```
WordCount getMostCommonWord(BinaryTreeNode<WordCount> wordNode) 
        throws EmptyCollectionException {

    WordCount current = wordNode.getElement();

    BinaryTreeNode left = wordNode.getLeftChild();
    BinaryTreeNode right = wordNode.getRightChild();

    WordCount maxLeft;
    WordCount maxRight;

    if (left != null) {
        maxLeft = getMostCommonWord(left);
        if (current.getCount() < maxLeft.getCount()) {
            current = maxLeft;
        }
    }

    if (right != null) {
        maxRight = getMostCommonWord(right);
        if (current.getCount() < maxRight.getCount()) {
            current = maxRight;
        }
    }

    return current;
}
```

This is also the first time I've posted here, so sorry if I'm doing it wrong. Any hints on how to make it work without a parameter would help a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just refactor so that you're using `this` instead of `wordNode`. And `left.getMostCommonWord()` instead of `getMostCommonWord(left)`.

Comment: what is the binary tree sorting? if it is sorted by word count, and you want the node with the highest word count, then that would be the right-most (left-most if descending) node. the recursion would be "if I have a right, return my right's result, otherwise return my result"

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Since you can't use a parameter, make this a method on the node class directly. Then use `this`.

This has the advantage of being generic, but will require that `T`, `wordCount` in your case, implements `Comparable`.

```
BinaryTreeNode<T> getMaxNode() 
        throws EmptyCollectionException {

    BinaryTreeNode<T> left = this.getLeftChild();
    BinaryTreeNode<T> right = this.getRightChild();

    BinaryTreeNode<T> currentMax = this;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> maxLeft;
    BinaryTreeNode<T> maxRight;

    if (left != null) {
        maxLeft = left.getMaxNode();
        if (this.getElement() < maxLeft.getElement()) {
            currentMax = maxLeft;
        }
    }

    if (right != null) {
        maxRight = right.getMaxNode();
        if (this.getElement() < maxRight.getElement()) {
            currentMax = maxRight;
        }
    }

    return currentMax;
}
```